# How do I find the parameter files for unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, parameters, path

I believe I have a file mix up  , because it keep saying the parameters don't exist . I need to find the parameters . I know its unity3d editor. I don't know where to go from their.

Comment: What is parameter files?

Comment: Can you tilt your screen a bit left please. I can't see it properly from your question.

Comment: @UmairM I will now be using this as a response to such similar questions, if you don't mind.